# how to add ConcurrencyCheck with data annotation while doing database first without modifying the designer?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5

this is the class generated by the designer;

```
Partial Public Class fredTest
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property data As String
    Public Property version As Integer
End Class
```

I'm trying to add the concurrency check by doing this;

```
<MetadataType(GetType(fredTestMeta))>
Partial Public Class fredTest
End Class

Public Class fredTestMeta
    <ConcurrencyCheck>
    Public Property version As Integer
End Class
```

and it doesn't work.

concurrency check does work if I use the designer to set it to fixed.

is it possible do make it work without playing with the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing database first the concurrency needs to be set in the edmx file and this is what the designer does.